# Python3 - Each thread to use n + 1 value within function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a script to send a post requests with some data that has been loaded from a JSON file.

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Mr",
    "firstname": "Joe",
    "lastname": "Blogs",
    "phonenumber": 7901893333
  },
  {
    "title": "Miss",
    "firstname": "Jane",
    "lastname": "Wang",
    "phonenumber": 7901894444
  },
  {
    "title": "Mrs",
    "firstname": "Rosie",
    "lastname": "Thomas",
    "phonenumber": 7901895555
  }
]
```

CODE:

```
import requests
import json
import threading

with open('data.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    data = json.loads(data_file.read())

def send_info():
    url = 'http://ptsv2.com/t/e092q-1537974317/post'

    payload = {
    'titleCode': data[0]["title"],
    'firstName': data[0]["firstname"],
    'lastName': data[0]["lastname"],
    'cellPhone': data[0]["phonenumber"] 
    }

    r = requests.post(url, params=payload)

    print(r.text)

threads = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    t = threading.Thread(target=send_info)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

At the moment all threads are just using the 'data[0]'.

How do I get one thread to use 'data[0]', the next to use 'data[1]' and the next to use 'data[2]'?

Comment: there's no point on using threads in Python if you want a proper multi-core processing. Use MultiProcessing instead. https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)
    print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

Where [1, 2, 3] is an array of arguments to be used as input to f() method.

source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Thank you for this answer, very helpful. When [1, 2, 3] is an undefined range, so this could be [1, 2,......., 899, 900] and that range length is found by len(data).  How would I go about making it adaptable to the amount of JSON data present?

Comment: Instead of [1,2,3] array use range(len(data))

Comment: In case it doesnt work (because range is not a list..), do list(range(len(data)))